# Why doesn't Perl provide headers when missing?

Tags: perl

If I forget to print headers,will get such an error in Perl:

```
 Premature end of script headers
```

But in PHP it's fine if I don't print any headers,why doesn't Perl do it automatically?

Answer (score 12):

PHP is a mishmash of a template language, programming language and web framework.

Perl is a programming language. It keeps templating and web framework functionality tucked away in optional modules (which is a good thing as it more easily allows for neatly organised code). If you want automatic headers and such, then use a web framework such as [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) or [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Perl is also generically used as a scripting language, PHP was predominantly created as a web scripting language, so, unless called in a manner to warn it not to, PHP assumes it needs to do it, where as perl thinks its a scripting tool for command line, so has to be told to actually do it.

Comment: That documentation says you will get an error if you try to use `header` after sending content (which is *because* headers are automatically sent).

Comment: What documentation? I think you're confusing Perl with something else (maybe a module).

Comment: @mpeters, I think you will find Quentin, is correctly referring to the PHP headers, as there was originally a comment before his

Answer (score 2):

Because you're probably executing your Perl scripts as CGI. Apache just executes the Perl script, takes its output and sends the lot to the browser. The poor Perl script doesn't know it's supposed to generate web output.

You're probably executing PHP using Apache's mod_php.